# Django:Backup and restore

Tags: django, django-database

I have been reading about process to do backup and restore in django.
The best i could come up with was to dumpdata. 
i.e. python manage.py dumpdata  >foo.json

Now to restore this data we will have to delete or drop the present table, then restore this json file using it as a fixture. i.e. do syncdb
Is there any particular way of doing this ? i.e. is there any process which can be used every-time we do backup and restore? 
I am looking for a tool like south, which can used for database backup and restore.

I am planning to get my site online.So any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not using a plain sql dump?

Answer (score 2):

The [django-dbbackup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbbackup/) package can do database backups and restores.

Answer (score 1):

For proper backup and restore, use the tools that came with your database.

If you *must* use django, write your own custom management commands (but again, I question the wisdom of this).